# filter view from url parameter with an intermediate model?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have been trying to figure out how to filter (get) the context of a page using the id from the current page.

I have a url http:/.../backend/projects/1/functions/1 corresponding to project detail page of project.id=1 and function.id=1

However, in my FunctionDetail view below. It returns all Function model objects - and is not filtered based on the current project.

How can I get the ids from the URLs to filter in the view? In addition I will like to access content of my RoletoFunction Objects in the template.

Should I be able to iterate through in the FunctionDetail like this:

```
 for f in function.roletofunction_set.all: 
    f.allocation
```

Have been trying to solve this for a few days on Google/Stackexchange but cant crack it.

Help v much appreciated!

Cheers,

Hamish

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    proj_name = models.CharField()
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='assigned_to')

class Capability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)

class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    capability = models.ForeignKey(Capability)
    performs_role = models.ManyToManyField('Role', through='RoletoFunction')

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    performs_func = models.ManyToManyField(Function, through='RoletoFunction')
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)

class RoletoFunction(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)
    name = models.CharField()
    allocation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

**urls.py**

```
# backend/projects/1/functions/1/
url(r'^projects/(?P<pk>\d+)/functions/(?P<function_id>\d+)/$', views.FunctionDetail.as_view(), name='function_detail'),

# /backend/projects/[id]/
url(r'^projects/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProjectDetail.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
class ProjectList(ListView):
    model = Project
    context_object_name = 'proj_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Project.objects.filter(assigned_to=user)

class FunctionDetail(DetailView):
    model = Function
    template_name = 'backend/function_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'function'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """return list of functions"""
        self.function = get_object_or_404(Function, name=self.args[2])
        return Function.objects.filter(id=self.args[2])
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how a Function is a part of a project. With 2 ManyToMany fields separating the two models, I'm not sure how you intend to relate them. A function can have many roles. And each role can have many projects. Is that what you want?

Comment: apologies, i ommitted a joining model called 'capabilities. I have edited toadd it in above.

Comment: And to fully answer the question, Yes, a function can have many roles and a role can part of many projects. The confusing element for me is how to relate them with the roletofunction model and still filter on the current project (from the url project id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override DetailView's `get_context_data` to add `RoletoFunction` model's data to context. For example:

```
class FunctionDetail(DetailView):
     ...
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FunctionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if 'function_id' in kwargs:  #this is how you can get function_id's data from url
            _id = int(kwargs['function_id'] or '0')
        else:
            _id = 0
        function =  Function.objects.get(id=_id)
        context['role_function'] = RoletoFunction.objects.filter(function=function)
        return context
```

Comment: thanks @ruddra for the help but all im getting is syntax errors, even when i try and remove the if: else: statement and attempt to assign the kwargs directly..the line that  supposdely has a syntax error is the else: statement....      `else:`

Comment: oh, actually `has_key` has  become deprecated(has_key() was removed in Python 3.x.). My bad for using that. You can use `in` instead. Check my edit. :)

Comment: for anyone interested, the part that was key for me `kwargs['function_id']` , the key name of each which is actually set in the urls.py  e.g. `url(r'^projects/(?P<pk>\d+)/functions/(?P<function_id>\d+)/$`